# Remove almost duplicated strings

Tags: arrays, string, perl, duplicates

Hi I have these strings and several other strings in an array.

```
    revised_1.4_1.4-1.05-jan
    revised_1.5_1.8-before
    revised_1.5_1.8-after
    revised_1.5_0.7-mid
    deleted&reviewed_0.9-0.8-1.05-jan
    deleted&reviewed_1.6_1.6-before
    deleted&reviewed_0.5_1.8-after
    deleted&uploaded_0.8_1.9-midweek
    deleted&uploaded_1.0_1.3-offweek
    accessedbeforesecondquarter_0.8._1.6-jan
    accessedbeforesecondquarter_0.9_1.7-feb
```

I need to keep one of the almost similar strings in the array. How can I code to get this array?

```
    revised_1.4_1.4-1.05-jan 
    deleted&reviewed_0.9-0.8-1.05-jan
    deleted&uploaded_0.8_1.9-midweek
    accessedbeforesecondquarter_0.8._1.6-jan
```

Here's my code and it doesn't seem to work fine for me to save the strings into an array.

```
my %seen;
my @strings = grep !$seen{ substr($_,0,2) }++, @strings;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keeping the spirit of what you tried:

```
my %seen;
my @result = grep {! $seen{(split "_",$_)[0]}++} <DATA>;
print @result;

__DATA__
revised_1.4_1.4-1.05-jan
revised_1.5_1.8-before
revised_1.5_1.8-after
revised_1.5_0.7-mid
deleted&reviewed_0.9-0.8-1.05-jan
deleted&reviewed_1.6_1.6-before
deleted&reviewed_0.5_1.8-after
deleted&uploaded_0.8_1.9-midweek
deleted&uploaded_1.0_1.3-offweek
accessedbeforesecondquarter_0.8._1.6-jan
accessedbeforesecondquarter_0.9_1.7-feb
```

result:

```
revised_1.4_1.4-1.05-jan
deleted&reviewed_0.9-0.8-1.05-jan
deleted&uploaded_0.8_1.9-midweek
accessedbeforesecondquarter_0.8._1.6-jan
```

Comment: Can you explain `(split "_",$_)[0]}++` this code. I was use decrement operator instead of `++` it is also work. What is the meaning of the `++` operator in your code?

Comment: @aja `(split "_", $_)` returns a list split with '_' with `[0]` you are taking the first element of the list and then increment the count for the hash. Any non-zero number is true in Perl in boolean context. So `'!1'` or `'!-1'` returns false. `grep` returns the elements that are true.